# ¿Cómo puedo saber con exactitud qué cambios traen las actualizaciones forzosas de Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows10

Hay alguna especie de listado de cambios puntuales en algún lado?

Algo diferente de `"se instaló X extensión"`, o `"se actualiza X programa"`.

¿No existe algún listado detallado, como las "notas de parche" de los juegos online, donde pueda saber exactamente qué es lo que Microsoft está metiendo o cambiando en mi pc?

Comment: Primero que versión de windows utilizas?

Comment: windows 10 professional

Comment: Esta pregunta no parece versar sobre programación o herramientas de programación dentro del alcance definido en El Centro de ayuda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En windows 10. vas a **configuración**, 
luego a **windows update**, 
y debajo del botón **buscar actualizaciones** 
te aparecerá **historial de actualizaciones**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Le das a **desinstalar actualización** y te saldrá una lista con los programas atualizados.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

También tienes la opción de copiar el nombre de la actualización y buscar mas detalles en la pagina de Microsoft.